# Expand collection elements in Watches window while debugging?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, intellij-idea

I somehow can only view the first 100 of my array in the `Watches` window. The three dots likely represent that there is more to be shown but I cannot find out how to expand the window. As you can see the `size = 10000` so there really are more objects to be shown.

So how do I show these objects?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IntelliJ IDEA only shows the first 100 by default. It is possible to adjust the range on the fly at any moment by right-clicking the collection in the `Watches` window and choose `Adjust Range`. Fill in two of the three field to specify the elements you want to show up. The range values persist until removed from the watch list.

[image]

Comment: How do I set the default to another number other than 100 so I wont have to do this every time?

Comment: @VMMF Good question.