# How to change the default number of elements from an array displayed in the Watches window of Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, watch

I'm using `Android Studio 2.1.1` and I'm debugging an `Android` app that deals with arrays of 500 elements. The default number of elements you can visualize in the Watches window of `Android Studio` is 100 elements. I've also seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921965/expand-collection-elements-in-watches-window-while-debugging/32966373?noredirect=1#comment64235472_32966373) that I'm able to adjust the range (amount) of elements that I can visualize. Is there a way to automatize these process by increasing the default number of displayed elements from an array in the watches window or when hovering the mouse in the array while debbuging so I won't manually have to expand the visualizing range every time I need to?